# Algebra Problem Olympiad

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, radicals

Prove that there are infinitely many pairs (n,k) of rational numbers such that 
$\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}=k$

I expressed  it as $n+\sqrt{n}=\frac {a^2}{b^2}$

but cant get any further. Could someone help.

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{n}$ must be rational.

Comment: yeah and that means n is rational too.

Comment: Can we ise an inductive approach here, first find The minimal value for $n$ that fits and assume $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{a}{b}$ check if this stands for $n+1$ ?

Comment: Where did you get this from? Yes, it doesn't stand for a particular majority in $\mathbb{N}$ haven't thought that through.

Comment: I was sent this by someone to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=\{3, 8, 15, \ldots, m^2-1, \ldots \}$. $X$ has infinite elements. Then, for $c \in X$, $c+1$ is a perfect square. It follows that

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2}}}= \sqrt{\frac{c+1}{c^2}}$$

The right-hand side is rational because $c \in X$, so the infinite set

$$\left\{\left(\frac{1}{c^2},\sqrt{\frac{c+1}{c^2}}\right), c \in X\right\}$$

of pairs of rational numbers is contained in the set of rational solutions.

Comment: This can be extended to all answers: $$\left\{(n,k)=\left(\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2},\frac{t}{t^2-1}\right)\bigg\vert \,t\in\mathbb Q, t>1\right\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$$

Comment: (And this is an answer without explaining how you got it.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$, $b$ be positive integers such that $a < b$ and $(a, \: b) = 1$. If $n = \dfrac{a^4}{(b^2 - a^2)^2}$ we have $$\begin{align*} \sqrt{n + \sqrt{n}} & = \sqrt{\frac{a^4}{(b^2 - a^2)^2} + \frac{a^2}{b^2 - a^2}} = \\ & = \sqrt{\frac{a^4 + a^2(b^2 - a^2)}{(b^2 - a^2)^2}} = \frac{ab}{b^2 - a^2} \end{align*}$$ which is a rational number. So the pair $\displaystyle (n, \: k) = \left(\frac{a^4}{(b^2 - a^2)^2}, \: \frac{ab}{b^2 - a^2}\right)$ is a solution. Are these all distinct? Since $(a, \: b) = 1$, we also have $(a^2, \: (b^2 - a^2)) = 1$, whence $n$ is a fraction in the reduced form, which implies that these solutions are pairwise distinct. Since they are obviously infinite, we are done.

Comment: This is an answer which does not explain how you got it.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\sqrt{n}=k^2-n$ irrational, so let $m=\sqrt{n}$. Then your equation is:

$$m^2+m-k^2=0$$

There is a general technique for solving such equations, but this equation can be solved more directly by rewriting it as:

$$(2m+1)^2-(2k)^2=1$$

So if you can find infinitely many rational solutions to $u^2-v^2=1$, with $u\geq 1,v\geq 0$ you can find infinitely many solutions to your original equation by setting $n=\left(\frac{u-1}{2}\right)^2$ and $k=\frac{v}{2}$.

Writing $u^2-v^2=(u-v)(u+v)$, we then need $u-v$ and $u+v$ to be rational inverses. So $u-v=\frac{p}{q}$ and $u+v=\frac{q}{p}$, with $0<p\leq q$ integers. (These requirements ensure $u\geq 1$ and $v\geq 0.$)

You get $$\begin{align}u&=\frac{q^2+p^2}{2pq}\\v&=\frac{q^2-p^2}{2pq}.\end{align}$$

Then $$\begin{align}k&=\frac{q^2-p^2}{4pq}\\n&=\frac{(q-p)^4}{16p^2q^2}.\end{align}$$

If $p\neq q$, let $r=\frac{p}{q-p}$ then you get $r+1=\frac{q}{q-p}$ and thus $$n=\frac{1}{16r^2(r+1)^2},\quad k=\frac{2r+1}{4r(r+1)}.$$ The value for $n$ is decreasing as $r$ increases, so we have a distinct solutions for any rational $r>0$. In particular, there are infinitely many solutions.

That gives all solutions except when $p=q$, which gives the values $n=0,k=0$.

If $s=2r$ then we get the slightly simpler formula:

$$n=\frac{1}{s^2(s+2)^2}, \quad k=\frac{s+1}{s(s+2)}$$

Letting $t=s+1$, we get:

$$n=\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2},\quad k=\frac{t}{t^2-1},\quad t> 1$$

Comment: Consider any Pythagorean triple, $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$.  Then $(\frac zy)^2-(\frac xy)^2 = 1$